# How do I get a VIEW value into a table?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a personal project using PostgreSQL and I'm stuck trying to figure out what the best way to approach this problem:

So in my project there's two tables: USERS and MATCHES. Inside MATCHES there's match results, one row for each, with the columns being ID, player1, player2, player1result, player2result, and winner. While in the USERS table there's ID, name, MatchesWon, MatchesTied, MatchesLost, GoalsScored, GoalsAgainst, and GoalDifference. What I would like to do is take these match results, analyze them and send them to the USERS table.

So for example, if in 5 matches, the winner was "Tom", the column MatchesWon for "Tom" should be 5. Now I can do this using a view, and I have, but there's a couple of things that I do not yet understand.

1. Can I use a view as a value? For example, create a table and determine that the MatchesWon value will use a view that counts all matches where winner equals that row's "name" value?
2. If 1 is possible or impossible, either way: is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1. you can use your view as table for select queries . 2. You can use trigger if you want to update the values in user table. Better to share the table structure and desired output example and also what query you have tried

Comment: How should I share the table structure? Sorry, I'm pretty new at this and I don't know what's the info you need.

Also, the query I used for MatchesWon for a "Tom" user is the following:

`CREATE VIEW tomwon AS SELECT COUNT(winner) FROM matches WHERE player1='tom' AND winner='tom';`